# Using a frameless hinge on a framed cabinet

Tags: cabinets, hinges

Accidentally bought hinge intended for frameless (I thought "full overlay" meant that it would work for my 1 7/16" overlay cabinet based on what some web site said about those being equivalent, but OK). I really need a "clip on" hinge, I guess, based on the existing hinge appearance (see below). However, since I have these frameless hinges already, can't I just put a little block of wood as seen in picture so that they'd sit flush with the frame? Are there any downsides other than perhaps aesthetic imperfection?

[image: picture of existing hinge and new ghost frameless hinge]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The frameless hinges will work but you'll need  larger pieces of wood because the hinges will need to be mounted further back than you show it. If this is a single hinge replacement, you'll have to change all the hinges on the door since the turn radius will be different. In this case, you'd be better off biting the bullet and getting the correct hinge.

Answer (score 2):

The opening geometry for that hinge would put a lot of stress on the frame of the cabinet, even with a block of wood behind it.
The adjustment availability to your door is less.

Bottom line...get the correct hinge and avoid the aggravation.